# Changing display Image when interacting to other display

Tags: coronasdk

I'm new in corona and I'm trying to make a very simple game for android. I have a two display which is "ball" and "stone" both of them have added a physics, now what I'm trying to do is to detect or check if the ball touches the stone then I will change the image of the ball.

Any thought will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps are given below -

local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()

local firstObject = display.newImage( "bkg_ firstObject.png" )
firstObject.x = display.contentWidth / 2
firstObject.y = 100

local secondObject = display.newImage( "bkg_secondObject.png" )
secondObject.x = display.contentWidth / 2
secondObject.y = 400
secondObject.myName = "secondObject"

physics.addBody( secondObject, "static", { friction=0.6, bounce=0.4 } )

local box1 = display.newImage( "crate.png" )
box1.x = 180; crate1.y = -50
box1.myName = "first box"

local box2 = display.newImage( "crate.png" )
box2.x = 180; crate2.y = -150
box2.myName = "second crate"

physics.addBody( box1, { density=3.0, friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 } )
physics.addBody( box2, { density=3.0, friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 } )

---- METHOD 1: Use table listeners (Local Method)

```
local function methodOfCollision( self, event )

    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then

    end
end
```

crate1.collision = methodOfCollision
crate1:addEventListener( "collision", crate1 )

crate2.collision = methodOfCollision
crate2:addEventListener( "collision", crate2 )

---- METHOD 2: Use a runtime listener (Global Method)

```
local function onGlobalCollision( event )

    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then

    end
end
```

Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onGlobalCollision )

This answer may help you.

Comment: You can use - crate1.preCollision = onPreCollision
crate1:addEventListener( "preCollision", crate1 )

crate1.postCollision = onPostCollision
crate1:addEventListener( "postCollision", crate1 )

Comment: Sir do you also know how to use sprite sheet?